# oracle, query joining issues "SQL command not properly ended"

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I would like to join 2 SQL queries in oracle, but I'm really not familiar with it, my structure seems correct to me, but I have this SQL error message: "[Err] ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"

So I have two queries:
the first one is:

```
select 
    campaign_id, count(*) as "number of emails sent"
from 
    dg_res_sent
where 
    dg_end_date > sysdate
group by campaign_id
```

and the second one is:

```
select 
    offer_name, 
    campaign_id, 
    offer_category as "link category", 
    count(*) as "number of clicks"
from 
    dg_res_click
where
    dg_end_date > sysdate
and
    SUBSTR(offer_name,1,3) = 'SKU'
group by 
    offer_name, 
    campaign_id, 
    offer_category
```

I want to do my join on campaign_id so I did:

```
select 
    offer_name, 
    campaign_id, 
    offer_category as "link category", 
    count(*) as "number of clicks",
    sent.nb_sent
from 
    dg_res_click
where
    dg_end_date > sysdate
and
    SUBSTR(offer_name,1,3) = 'SKU'
inner join
    (select 
        campaign_id, count(*) as "nb_sent"
    from 
        dg_res_sent
    where 
        dg_end_date > sysdate
    group by campaign_id) sent
on 
    sent.campaign_id = dg_res_click.campaign_id
group by 
    offer_name, 
    campaign_id, 
    offer_category
```

any idea why I get this message:

> [Err] ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: shouldn't inner join be placed before where clause?

Comment: I removed the MySQL and SQL Server tags, because the question is explicitly about Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

You have placed `inner join` at wrong position.It should be before the `where` clause

```
select 
    dg_res_click.offer_name, 
    dg_res_click.campaign_id, 
    dg_res_click.offer_category as "link category", 
    count(*) as "number of clicks",
    sent.nb_sent
from 
    dg_res_click 
inner join
    (select 
        campaign_id, count(*) as nb_sent
    from 
        dg_res_sent
    where 
        dg_end_date > sysdate
    group by campaign_id) sent
on 
    sent.campaign_id = dg_res_click.campaign_id

where
    dg_res_click .dg_end_date > sysdate
and
    SUBSTR(dg_res_click.offer_name,1,3) = 'SKU'
group by 
    dg_res_click.offer_name, 
    dg_res_click.campaign_id, 
    dg_res_click.offer_category,
    sent.nb_sent
```

Comment: thanks, it seems correct to me, but I have this error message: ""SENT"."NB_SENT": invalid identifier"

Comment: but it won't be a string anymore, no?

Comment: its just an alias so the quotes are not required

Comment: And in mysql back ticks are used for strings.. \`nb sent\`

Comment: in your first select should it be dg_res_click.offer_name and dg_res_click.campaign_id instead of sent.offer_name and sent.campaign_id ?

Comment: also in the group by should it be dg_res_click.offer_name and be dg_res_click.offer_category ? I tried but then I have "[Err] ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: That was because `sent.nb_sent` was not inlcuded in the group by clause.. Apart from columns which have aggregate functions, rest should be in `group by ` clause

Answer (score 2):

Your Inner join should be placed before your where clause.